# loop returns same value multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a WordPress loop where I list the data. I create a button dynamically and set their ids. 
When I set that id into a textbox I can see that all buttons have different ID because I increment the number each time. Until here everything is okay and working fine.

but need to use javascript for setting the textbox value with value of button ID.

I use this following code:

```
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.p-name-x').click(function(){
        $('#dynamic-field').val($(".the-prod-counter").val());        
    });
    alert($(".the-prod-counter").val());
});
</script>
```

on my `$('.p-name-x').click(function()` x should be changed with the number if ID i get from the loop.

on my alert it always gives the first ID. For example if I have 3 buttons the alert gives 3 times the first id!

How can get the alert to show the other numbers as well?

------------- **EDIT** --------------

Here is part of my code

```
<?php
$type = 'stiel_privatkunden';
$args=array('stiel_privatkunden_cat' => $post_slug, 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'order'=>'ASC');
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$i=1;
$idh=1;
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
if($i%2==0) {
?>


<div class="row" style="background:#f3f3f3" id="<?php the_field('prod_slug'); ?>">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</figure>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="padding:20px;">
<div class="title_content">
<div class="the-title"><?php the_title();?></div>
<div class="the-desc"><?php the_field('description'); ?></div>

<?php if( get_field('passende_Produkte') ): ?>
<div class="vc_toggle vc_toggle_square vc_toggle_color_black vc_toggle_color_inverted vc_toggle_size_md">
<div class="vc_toggle_title" tabindex="0"><h4>passende Produkte</h4><i class="vc_toggle_icon"></i></div>
<div class="vc_toggle_content" style="display: none;">
<p><?php the_field('passende_Produkte'); ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?> 


<?php if( get_field('link_mehr_erfahren') ): ?>
<a href="<?php the_field('link_mehr_erfahren'); ?>" class="vcex-button theme-button flat medium inline animate-on-hover wpex-dhover-0" style="background:#3fbfef;color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #3fbfef;border-radius:0px;" data-wpex-hover="{&quot;background&quot;:&quot;#ffffff&quot;,&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#3fbfef&quot;}"><span class="theme-button-inner">mehr erfahren</span></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_field('link_jetz_anfragen') ): ?>
<a href="<?php the_field('link_jetz_anfragen'); ?>" class="vcex-button theme-button flat medium inline animate-on-hover wpex-dhover-0 popup-form p-name-<?php echo $idh; ?>" style="background:#3fbfef;color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #3fbfef;border-radius:0px;" data-wpex-hover="{&quot;background&quot;:&quot;#ffffff&quot;,&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#3fbfef&quot;}" onclick="setValue()"><span class="theme-button-inner">jetzt anfragen</span></a>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>


<!--<input type="text" name="the-prod-name" class="the-prod-name-<?php echo $idh; ?>" value="<?php the_field('prod_slug');?>">-->
<input type="hidden" name="the-prod-counter" class="the-prod-counter" value="<?php echo the_field('prod_slug') . '-'. $idh; ?>">
<!--<input type="text" name="the-prod-idk" class="the-prod-idk" value="<?php //echo $idh; ?>"> -->

<script>    

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.p-name').click(function(){
    $('#dynamic-field').val($(".the-prod-counter").val());        
});

//alert($(".the-prod-counter").val());

});

</script>

</div>
</div>

<br/> 

<?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: i dont see any loop. can you share all relevant code?

Comment: I would imagine your problem is with the selector `".the-prod-counter"`. I assume you are trying to pick the current `the-prod-counter`, but that selector is always searching from the root element, and thus is finding the same elements in the same order, and gives the value of the first one only. You need to make it relative to the element clicked on -- how exactly is impossible to see without knowing your DOM.